# coudn't delete a key when it's also a foreing key in another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi sorry if it's a duplicate question but i've been looking all over stack and also everywhere  for solution or even a similiar probleme of mine and can't find it So basically i'm trying to delete a key from a table while that exact key is a foreing key in another table (both tables are InnoDB and it's set on cascade for both uptade and delete ) i get the following error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'amphi ' in C:\wamp64\www\E-booking9\profile\admin\delete\Dclass.php on line 17

i don't have datetime format on the table i'm trying to delete it from (it's a classroom table)  i do have a datetime format on the the other table where the key is a foreing key at (it's a reservation table)
here is the code
and when i wrote the delete code in phpmyadmin in the sql view it worked the classroom got deleted

```
<?php
// error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include('../../connexionDB.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['CR']) ||$_SESSION['CR'] == ""){
   echo 'no id found'
}else {
    $AS = $_SESSION['CR'];
  
}
echo $AS;
$sql = "DELETE FROM `classroom` WHERE code_class =:c ";
    $statement = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam('c', $AS, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// execute the statement
if ($statement->execute()) {
    echo 'publisher id  was deleted successfully.';
 
      }
?>
```

Comment: $AS value data type is string, integer or something else? you've used PDO::PARAM_INT meaning it would be used as an integer.

Comment: Please show us the table schema and add what `$AS` actually contains. We need as much details as possible. However, I don't see how the error you've posted have anything to do with foreign key constraints?

Comment: @nazim OMG why havn't i noticed that thank you so mcuh it's working now